# DM-script fast 3D offset

Tags: dm-script

Trying to implement offset function for 3D data. This is a test code,

```
image ThreeDOffSet(image img3D, number shiftx, number shiftY) {
    image img3DTmp, rst
    img3DTmp:=img3D.ImageClone()
    img3DTmp=img3D[icol+shiftx, irow+shifty, iplane]
    //img3D_.showImage()
    return img3DTmp
}
void main() {
    number startTick, stopTick
    startTick = GetHighResTickCount()
    image img3D:=exprSize(200, 200, 1024,random())
    image rst:=img3D.ThreeDOffSet(10, -6)
    stopTick = GetHighResTickCount()
    img3D.showImage()
    rst.showImage()
    result("\nDuration:"+(stopTick-StartTick)/GetHighResTicksPerSecond()+"sec\n")
}
main()
```

Can DM-script do faster than this?

Answer (score 2):

Found a faster way. This is 20 times faster.

```
image ThreeDOffSet(image img3D, number shiftx, number shiftY, number method) {
    number startTick, stopTick, d0,d1, d2, x, y
    image rst
    startTick = GetHighResTickCount()
    if (method==0) {
        rst:=img3D.ImageClone()
        rst=img3D[icol+shiftx, irow+shifty, iplane]
        stopTick = GetHighResTickCount()
    }
    else if (method==1) {
        img3D.get3dsize(d0,d1,d2)
        rst:=exprSize(d0,d1,d2,0)
        x=shiftX
        y=ShiftY
        rst[x,y,0,d0,d1,d2]=img3D.slice3(0,0,0,0,d0-x,1, 1,d1-y,1,2,d2,1)
        stopTick = GetHighResTickCount()
    }
    result("\nDuration:"+(stopTick-StartTick)/GetHighResTicksPerSecond()+"sec\n")
    return rst
}
void main() {
    number method
    image rst
    image img3D:=exprSize(200, 200, 1024,random())
    getnumber("method", method,method) 
    rst:=img3D.ThreeDOffSet(10, 6,method)
    img3D.showImage()
    rst.showImage()
    
}
main()
```

Comment: Need a little bit more of "if-else" to handle the sign of shiftX and shiftY.

Comment: At this point, I realized this is just a demonstration of sliceN() function. It is fast because it is just re-indexing. Using intrinsic variable is slow because all pixels are re-assigned - it is still relative fast due to parallel processing, but the massive assignments add up. I guess using "sliceN" is the fasted way to do this.

Comment: Yes, sliceN (and its partners) are the fasted way (in scripting) to address and use subvolume data.